# My app freezes only in iOS 4.3.5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode4

My iPhone app consists of a tabBarController and data is being shown by making a synchronous request to the server.

So, whenever I navigate from one tab to the other or from background to foreground, in most of the cases the app freezes giving me this error message three times in the log.

> +[CATransaction synchronize] called within transaction

I face the same issue referred in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7196197/catransaction-synchronize-called-within-transaction) but with iOS 4.3.5(iPod) only.

I tried to research a lot but no luck.
Please help me in fixing this issue.

Thanks.